# Can't override default bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can not override the default css. Any help?

HTML:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--Custom CSS-->
<link fref="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

CSS:

```
 .navbar ,.navbar-defualt {
    background-color: red;
    border-color: blue;
}
```

I have tried targeting .navar-custom and .navbar-inverse

Comment: Your custom.css file linking has a typo, I updated my answer to cover that up. You've also written the .navbar-default as .navbar-defualt which will not work. Remember to focus on the correct spelling, it's important in these things!

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** Your CSS is linked incorrectly. Change the `<link fref="">` to `<link href="">`. So just a little typo here which explains it all.

Just to make sure you've linked your `custom.css` to your HTML file correctly, try to change your navigation background color like following:

```
.navbar-default {
   background-color: #00ffff !important;
}
```

If that does absolutely nothing at all, your CSS file is not linked to your HTML file and you should check what's wrong with the file path.

If it works, you should go for the `.navbar-default` only, since **you don't necessarily need to override `.navbar` style properties** when you're already doing it for the `.navbar-default`.

It's now safe to say it works and **remove the `!important` markup**, since it should work perfectly well without it.

Comment: Finally an answer that isn't promoting the use of '!important' for such an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to override navbar-default class, then target same class. This is working.

Let me explain you this, in your code you are using navbar, navbar-default but those two classes are relevant to same class definition, so you do not need to use ','(comma). Instead of that use '.navbar.navbar-default'. This will give you the working CSS.

```css
.navbar-default {
    background-color: red;
    border-color: blue;
}
```